# How do I prevent new programmers pushing `console.log` to Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, push, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to prevent new programmers pushing code containing `console.log` to Bitbucket using pipelines. How I'll do it?

Comment: why would you want that? woudn't it be better to prevent them from being deployed to production? If you use grunt you could use [grunt-remove-logging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-remove-logging) to remove them. console.log might be useful for debugging local.

Comment: I've already told them. They use it for debugging but the repository is a production repository. We don't use Node.js.

Comment: @olibiaz, it is not a file. It is JavaScript function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is not too important to prevent the push, but that it’s enough to make sure that the build fails if `console.log()` encountered, you could implement a script step which greps the codebase. I’m doing something like this myself with Bb Pipelines, both with `console.log` and `debugger`.

The basic approach for that looks something like this:

```
foundfiles=$(fgrep -rli "console.log" --include='*.js' $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/path/to/files)
result="$?"
if [ "$result" = "0" ]
then
    echo "Found in $foundfiles"
    exit 1
fi
```

A Bash script including code such as the above could then be run by your pipeline and will fail if `console.log` is found.